# Django : I have a save() which is failing. How can I see the SQL that's generated?

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I have a failing model.save() in my Django app. How can I see the SQL that was generated by it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django FAQ: ["How can I see the raw SQL queries Django is running?"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running)